# How to decrypt data with public key

Tags: .net, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

Similar questions were asked many times but I was looking for an answer for 2 days and didn't find what I'm looking for. First of all, I have fair understanding of public/private key security from consuming standpoint. I never looked into the mathematics behind it. I understand that normally you use a public key to encrypt data and a private key to decrypt it. I'm also aware of the other pair of operations: signing data with a private key and verifying it with a public key. In .NET there is RSACryptoServiceProvider implementing or wrapping all those operations. If we look at the Verify method, it is declared as this

```
public bool VerifyHash(byte[] rgbHash, string str, byte[] rgbSignature)
```

My problem is that instead of verifying I would like to decrypt the signature data into the original hash which was signed with the private key. Now, I'm a bit confused. I found many answers stating that this is impossible but is it impossible from the API standpoint or from the mathematical standpoint? I would guess that it might be not possible only from the .NET API standpoint because if I use OpenSSL and do this

```
.\openssl.exe rsautl -verify -certin -inkey dev.crt -in signature.dat -out original.dat
```

I can decrypt the signature (signature.dat) into the original value (original.dat) that signature was created from. I believe that proves that mathematically it is possible.

Now the big question is there a way to do this with .NET, any workarounds, any libraries, is there anything what will do for me what OpenSSL is capable of doing. Please don't suggest to execute OpenSSL from the code. I cannot package it with the application. I need something else, ideally finding a workaround with the existing RSACryptoServiceProvider.

**Updated step by step example:**

I created a hash (128 bytes)

```
3D 0C 20 5C 73 DD 81 73 2A 41 F8 C7 A1 32 86 A5
F5 B5 D4 80 E0 0E 43 D0 7C 81 37 5F E5 AA 85 2A
02 EC 63 FA B1 87 44 92 E7 6D AA 96 EA 5E AA 6D
FC 38 8E C4 21 F6 7E D5 2A C5 9E 0F 27 2A D7 B9
2C C8 7C CF 8E 52 B1 FD AF 1C E6 80 BB 68 81 55
DC 25 7B 8D ED 22 64 87 0F 4D 08 6A B1 33 74 FA
C3 9E AA 12 4A 56 01 AA A5 A8 5E 75 F5 A4 8F EF
F7 E4 AA DB 58 E7 61 96 F7 40 B7 A1 CA 49 E5 FC
```

Then I executed

```
.\openssl.exe rsautl -sign -inkey dev.key -in hash.dat -out signed_hash.dat
```

to generate a signature where the signed hash result is this. It's 256 bytes

```
69 A3 DF A1 F6 4C 88 8B 83 E7 C1 BD 4E 12 D6 24
4B 5F 52 23 A4 3B 4F 27 11 37 C0 4C FA 99 3D 43
2B E5 0E 37 EF BB 2B 10 FF 28 4D 84 93 5A A2 75
52 DA C8 83 75 6A B2 29 91 79 AC 0C 12 8D C6 50
3A B4 71 CA 3F CD 15 73 2C 33 1E FA 4D E3 35 3A
68 A5 6E 1D 2B FD 91 03 3D 2E 97 C0 1A 4F A7 E2
FF 65 5A F9 96 3E 1B 68 A6 57 43 B4 62 35 32 F5
17 DF 76 55 8F 89 81 34 F2 B6 24 83 B8 76 8D E3
AD DB 7E 38 DE C0 94 5B 90 15 D7 4F 25 86 90 1C
B4 12 94 A4 0E BD 76 BB CF 54 2F 24 4D DE B5 8D
C8 40 DD 16 81 50 20 BD 11 A1 65 07 9B 00 D8 C1
60 D9 B2 4F 64 F7 4E 02 A7 B6 8B E6 2A D1 AC EF
3C E7 C5 4D 95 6D 70 B7 31 A2 60 AE 37 D3 83 21
23 BD 25 34 1E B7 D9 EA 05 7A A3 C3 9C DB DA A4
A6 14 11 C6 40 0D BD CB DD C2 F2 87 3A B8 A2 E3
7E 80 D5 8B 01 91 4B B2 0A 42 54 B6 3B 7F 41 3C
```

Then if I do this

```
.\openssl.exe rsautl -verify -certin -inkey dev.crt -in signed_hash.dat -out original_hash.dat
```

I get back my original hash. The public exponent value retrieved from the RSAParameters for the public key is this

```
01 00 01
```

and the Modulus is this

```
aa 0e 02 74 4c b5 06 87 f6 ae 4c 2c 71 76 59 7a
84 47 07 db 8e dd 8a 58 2c ba e5 1b 91 45 3e de
7d a9 d4 0a b9 cf 9f c2 19 cf af d3 30 fd 55 fb
81 d0 ef 68 ef c7 b0 fc 49 c9 4f fd 20 e9 ea 04
31 57 8f c2 1e 85 76 86 63 12 e0 00 01 17 02 80
76 fc f9 bc 09 61 80 6b a3 0b 8e de 1d b2 2f d6
ed 18 32 4b 03 0b 3b 2c ca 75 b6 85 95 20 5a 16
dc 4f 33 4b 97 84 fe 3f 9f 04 5b ba 56 44 73 aa
9f b0 7d 44 f4 58 ea a2 9d 35 d9 5c 8d 2d 39 a8
ce ee 19 24 9e 78 74 dc 6d 16 2b d7 24 bf 80 fa
a6 12 bf bd 89 cd 47 d0 bd 19 21 7d 3d 65 7b 06
9b 24 55 3c ca 4c 63 ce 40 ad a3 c5 72 cf 66 79
e0 f2 23 05 fa 20 32 b0 02 96 f1 a3 82 40 b4 b9
ac 9c f1 cf 83 a3 f0 50 83 81 b6 d7 f8 5f 93 21
71 0b f9 26 87 3d 61 17 cc 0c 09 09 b4 40 e4 92
45 fb 77 ca 94 cb 15 fb 54 68 4a c3 31 2d 57 09
```

What I need to do is to retrieve the original hash from the signed hash in my C#.NET code and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: But that is exactly what signature verification (and the method `VerifyHash()`) does under the hood: it "decrypts" the signature with the public key to reveal the hash, then hashes the data being verified, and then checks that the two hashes are identical.

Comment: That is great. And in this case I can rephrase the question. How can I get to that buffer with that decrypted value? I just need that value. For my particular scenario I don't have the original value which I could pass to the VarifyHash, I need RSACryptoServiceProvider to give me the decrypted value and that's it. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: RSA signatures have two families, PKCS works like you describe and it is possible to recover the expected hash value (but not with .NET RSA API). PSS is a different variant which doesn’t allow recovery, just the ability to answer “correct” or “incorrect”.

Comment: Interesting to know but I guess in my case it is PKCS because I can recover it at least with OpenSSL. I'm still struggling to do it in code. I'm trying to play with the code mentioned in the answer below, that math with BigIntegers but I'm still unable to recover the hash. I think I'm missing something important, maybe additional encoding the standard algorithm does or padding or something of that kind but when I do {Signature} ^ {Exponent} mod {Modulus} the result is not even close to the original hash value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible using .NET crypto API's, at least I was not able to find a way. I was forced to re-implement the RSA algorithm using BigInteger. It's surprisingly straight forward.

1. Convert the signature, public exponent, and key modulus to BigIntegers.
2. Call `BigInteger.ModPow(signature, exponent, modulus)`.
3. Convert the result to a byte[]; this is the hash you're looking for.

Be aware of endianness and sign issues...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268207(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is some information on the subject that is specific to Java (and does not have the endianness issues you will face in .NET)...
https://www.nayuki.io/page/java-biginteger-was-made-for-rsa-cryptography

Comment: I tried the approach you suggested. I retrieved RSAParameters from the RSACryptoServiceProvider PublicKey and used used the retrieved {Exponent} and {Modulus} in the expression {Signature} ^ {Exponent} mod {Modulus}, basically this call BigInteger.ModPow(signature, exponent, modulus) but the result is not even close to the original value. The original value was 128 bytes. The result is 256 bytes and no parts of it resemble the original value. Apparently I'm missing extra decryption or padding or something but I still don't understand what.

Comment: @Alex, did you reverse the byte[]'s before converting to BigInteger? This is the endianness issue I mentioned, BigInteger expects, and produces byte[]'s in little endian format. You must reverse the bytes going in, and then reverse the bytes coming out.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It doesn't matter if I reverse the bytes before creating BigInteger out of the buffer or don't do that the result is still 256 bytes which does not resemble  my original hash. By the way should the result be 128 bytes or it will be 256 bytes and then I have to find my hash among those removing padding or doing something else? Once again my original hash was 128 bytes. After I signed it with OpenSSL it became 256 bytes. May be I have to preprocess that signature somehow before passing into the ModPow?

Comment: If you're able to post the signature, key components, and original hash (or test samples of each), I can verify whether my implementation works. I'd be happy to just post the working code, but it's proprietary, so I cannot.

Comment: I updated the original question adding the original hash, signed hash, exponent and modulus I retrieve from the RSAParameters object for the public key. Did you have a chance to try it? Did it work?